# Struct of struct or pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

What is the best/fastest way ?

**Struct of struct:**

```
struct Sheet{
    u8 status; // to check if empty ?
    u8  reserve0;
    u8  reserve1;
    u8  reserve2;
    struct words words[1024];
};

struct Book {
    int id;
    struct Sheet sheet[64];
};
```

*In this case, how to check if the `sheet` table is empty or not ? I need to add a `status` for each sheet ?*

or

**Pointer table of struct**

```
struct Sheet{
    u8  reserve0;
    u8  reserve1;
    u8  reserve2;
    struct words words[1024];
};

struct Book {
    int id;
    struct Sheet* sheet[64];
};
```

I don't need to use `malloc` since they are fixed table.

In the *struct of struct*, I can initialize by setting `status` but for *pointer to struct*, I can initialize with `bookinstance.sheet[] = NULL` or something like this.

I am pretty lost with `pointers`, `struct` and `malloc`. I come from `Ruby`...

**To be clear:**

I want not more than 64 `sheet` in my `book` instance. Maybe only 3 will be used or 64... But I want to be able to add them and check them with a number from 0 to 63.

Comment: I'm pretty lost too... Do you want each book to contain exactly 64 sheets, some of which may be empty (invalid)? In which case - yes, you can maintain an array of 64 sheet pointers, and if any of them is empty (invalid), then set it to `NULL`.

Comment: I'll go with pointers list then. Better for initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To a certain extent it depend on what you mean by "faster".
How your code will interact with these elements will change that.  In general; however, there are very few times you would likely see any significant effect of CPU time.

Note that in option 2 Book only allocates an array of pointers so you will have to add code (and overhead) to allocate Sheets for the pointers to point to.

The first option would seem cleaner as long as you are not intending on some Sheets to be shared among books.

Also, if you are copying books, option 2 would be faster since you would only be copying pointer rather then the entire Sheet struct.

Comment: Thank you, when I add a sheet, I won't remove anything after that, just change parameters/status. Anyway, for my case both options are ok but the second option could be better for programming because 1-if I copy, only a list of pointers, 2-can check easily if it's empty by just checking the pointer instead of for loop on `sheet[i].status`

Comment: You're welcome, enjoy coding.  One thing, be really careful with the pointers they present a lot of opportunity for null pointer references and memory leaks.  Do lots of null checking and make sure you release the memory for them sheets when you delete a book or one goes out of scope.